# Constraints on sending mail using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When sending mail using Graph API

> Per User, Per App ID has a maximum limit of 10,000 requests in 10 minutes

We recognize there are restrictions.

I referred to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/04/07/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/).

When sending mail by setting 10 persons to TO, CC and BCC of mail - will it be 1 request or 10 requests?
I will be saved if you give me a professor.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the article you're referring to ([Throttling in Outlook API and MS Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/04/07/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/)) is not the only limitation. When it comes to sending emails another one important one is [Exchange Online limitation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx) which is 10k recipients **per day** for all the plans (screenshot is from linked article):

[image: Exchange Online sending limits]

In this case wording is more clear so it's clear that 10 addresses in `To`, `CC` and `BCC` altogether will count as 10 emails.

Answering your initial question - against the throttling you linked, sending email with multiple recipients will count as single request. However, once you send 10k emails in the same day you'll reach Exchange Online daily limit.

Also remember that Exchange Online is not designed for bulk mailing in general ([source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_o365b/sending-bulk-mass-emails-using-office-365-outlook/3ec04ca2-416a-40fe-af37-077f3267698d)).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
I was able to understand the specification.
I will implement it taking into consideration both Exchange Online restrictions and MS Graph limitations.